# ¿Como puedo hacer para poder jugar varias veces en mi juego de preguntas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
*{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: Verdana;
}

.contenedor{
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 2px solid;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Juego de Preguntas</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
 <script></script>
</head>
<body> <!-- div preguntas y respuestas -->
 <div class="contenedor">
  <div id="preg"></div>
  <div id="Rtas"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Verificar respuesta" onclick="verificar();"> 
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //array preguntas
 var preguntas = [
 "¿Qué sabe hacer un desarrollador fullstack?",
 "¿Qué lenguaje sirve para hacer backend?",
 "¿Qué lenguaje es interpretado por el navegador?",
 ];
    //array respuestas
    var respuestas = [
    ["Ambos", "Solo Front-end", "Solo Back-end", "Ninguno"],
    ["PHP", "CSS3", "Bootstrap", "HTML5"],
    ["Javascript", "Java", "Cobol", "MS-DOS"]
    
    ];
   
  
 
 
 
 

 

  //Numero aleatorio de preguntas
  var indice_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*preguntas.length);

  var respuestas_posibles = respuestas[indice_aleatorio];

  var posiciones = [0,1,2,3];
  var respuestas_reordenadas = [];
  var norepeat = false 
  var respuesta_correcta;

 for(i in respuestas_posibles){
  var posicion_aleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random()*posiciones.length);
   if(posicion_aleatoria == 0 && norepeat == false){
    respuesta_correcta = i;
      norepeat = true
 }
 respuestas_reordenadas[i] =respuestas_posibles[posiciones[posicion_aleatoria]];
 posiciones.splice(posicion_aleatoria,1);
}

 var texto_respuestas = "";
  for(i in respuestas_reordenadas){
   texto_respuestas += '<input type="radio" name="answers" value="'+i+'"<label>'+ 
   respuestas_reordenadas[i] + '</label> <br>';
}
  //genera contenido en los elementos en el body
  document.getElementById('preg').innerHTML = preguntas[indice_aleatorio]
  document.getElementById('Rtas').innerHTML = texto_respuestas;
 

   //función para verificar si la respuesta es correcta o no
   function verificar(){
  var lista = document.querySelector('input[name=answers]:checked').value;
      valor = respuestas_reordenadas[lista];
      respuesta_acertada = respuestas_posibles[0];
      if (respuesta_acertada == valor) {
         alert("La respuesta es correcta");
     } 
  else {
        alert("La respuesta es incorrecta" );
       }
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

tengo un juego de preguntas casi terminado , lo único que me falta es que al momento de evaluar la respuesta si esta es correcta me formule una nueva pregunta, ya intente declarar las variables fuera de la función comprobar pero no me dice que las variables no están definidas.
tengo un juego de preguntas casi terminado , lo único que me falta es que al momento de evaluar la respuesta si esta es correcta me formule una nueva pregunta, ya intente declarar las variables fuera de la función comprobar pero no me dice que las variables no están definidas.
tengo un juego de preguntas casi terminado , lo único que me falta es que al momento de evaluar la respuesta si esta es correcta me formule una nueva pregunta, ya intente declarar las variables fuera de la función comprobar pero no me dice que las variables no están definidas.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es que uses un arreglo de objetos y que los vayas recorriendo cada vez que respondes una pregunta, algo más o menos así como en el siguiente ejemplo.

```js
const preguntas = [
    {
        pregunta: 'pregunta 1',
        respuesta: 'respuesta 1',
        opciones: ['opcion 1', 'opcion 2']
    },
    {
        pregunta: 'pregunta 2',
        respuesta: 'respuesta 2',
        opciones: ['opcion 1', 'opcion 2']
    },
    {
        pregunta: 'pregunta 3',
        respuesta: 'respuesta 3',
        opciones: ['opcion 1', 'opcion 2']
    },
];

let indice_pregunta_actual = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    asignarTextoPregunta();

    document.getElementById('btn_siguiente_pregunta').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        siguientePregunta();
    })
});

function asignarTextoPregunta() {
    const texto_pregunta = document.getElementById('pregunta');
    texto_pregunta.textContent = preguntas[indice_pregunta_actual].pregunta;
}

function siguientePregunta() {
    if ((indice_pregunta_actual + 1) < preguntas.length) {
        indice_pregunta_actual++;
        asignarTextoPregunta();
    } else {
        alert('No hay mas preguntas :)');
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Pregunta: <span id="pregunta"></span></p>
<button id="btn_siguiente_pregunta">Siguiente pregunta</button>
```